# Java compareTo method basics

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java and trying to solve some basic questions. One of my friends asked me to explain what can go wrong with this piece of code.
To me it looks perfectly fine.
I even tried it out and it works.

Can you guys help me out with it?

```
public int compareTo(Object o){
   Employee emp = (Employee) o;
   return this.id - o.id;
}
```

I could not find any good explanations for it.
Also id is an integer.

Comment: I don't see anything that can go wrong except if the Object passed as the argument is not of type Employee or an Employee subclass. You can check for this with the `instanceof` operator.

Comment: Yeah,I agree with @Insertusernamehere,what an alias...

Comment: Even I asked him the same doubts, but it was made sure that argument will always be of the type Employee.

Comment: Take look to [Java Tutorials: Object ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

Comment: @Insert username here I agree. That's the only problem I can see -- you may be attempting to subtract a null value from an integer, in which case bad things would happen. :-)

Comment: It's poor practice to have 2 variables with the same name, even if they're not of the same scope... Presumably, `emp` exists outside of the function? And you're casting it to `Employee` and assigning it to a new local variable `emp`?

Comment: Of course, it might make more sense to define it as `compareTo(Employee o)` (so that you don't need to do `instanceof`), unless you must conform to a superclass or interface definition of the method.

Comment: The second line of the function is, of course, nonsense.  (Or was until it was edited.)

Comment: @Mayank Agarwal Even though other code may not ever pass anything into it but Employee class instances doesn't mean that it will always be an Employee that is passed as it can accept any instance of an Object.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that if always an Employee instance is passed, do you see any other problems. As I have already given that answer.

Answer (score 3):

`Comparable` is an interface with a generic, so it should be `Comparable<Employee>`. (So you are sure that you compare an Employee with an Employee and not an Employee with a number.)

```
Employee emp = (Employee) emp;
```

Make sense?

You cast `emp` to `Employee` and put that in `emp`. Maybe you mean `(Employee) o`

```
return this.id - o.id;
```

You use `o` which is `Object`, and `Object` don't have `.id` Maybe you mean `emp.id`?

Comment: Made that change, and its safe to assume that the object passed will always be an instance of Employee.

Comment: No, it's not safe. You don't know what you will pass to it.

Comment: This is told to me as a part of question that Employee instance will be passed only.

Comment: Even if you're sure, it's always good to confirm by doing instanceof

Comment: Good call above. I suspected it to be Employee (o), but shouldn't we still be subtracting this.id - emp.id?

Comment: Object as param is the wrong thing that could exists, it allows you to put everything inside it without say nothing. You don't want to change because it will never happen? Well, another problem: You use Comparator as raw type.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that `id` is unique, and there is not integer overflow (which would require negative `id`s), that code should work as expected. On the other hand, if two `Emp` (considered different) can have the same `id` (because it is not the identifier we expect it to be by its name), then it could lead to the situation where two `Emp` are considered equal when in fact they are not.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the emp instance to do anything with... If you're trying to compare an `Employee` (`this`) to `Object o` that is always an `Employee`, then you want to `return this.id - emp.id;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compareTo(Employee o){
   return this.id - o.id;
}
```

If you're really a stickler:

```
public int compareTo(Object o){
   long thisId = this.id;
   long oId = o.id;
   long result = thisId - oId;
   if (result > Integer.MAX_VALUE) result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   if (result < Integer.MIN_VALUE) result = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It becomes tricky when you can't guaranteed that id is positive or negative. tricky part is, If id becomes negative than subtraction may overflow and produce incorrect result

Comment: It won't overflow if it's simply negative. It's an `int`, not an `unsigned int`. It will underflow at a very negative number, just as it will overflow at a very positive number. Not of huge concern here probably.

Comment: That is the catch here, if the number provided is very negative, it will cause overflow. As we are subtracting, a very positive number wont really affect.

Comment: Fair enough. It sounded as if you meant that it would usually overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Employee) {
            Employee emp = (Employee) o;
            return this.id - emp.id;
        }else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter not of type Employee!");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think thats ok. What's the problem if id is negative?

Answer (score -2):

compareTo() is also a reserved function usesd when comparing strings. So maybe he wants you to note that methods with the same name can cause issues.

Comment: compareTo() is a method *every* `Comparable` class implements, so your answer is at best misleading.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? Are you saying that `compareTo()` only applies to `String`? I suggest you read [the Java tutorial entry: "Object ordering"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)!